# How to bot Send Message via itself?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How to bot Send Message via itself?

It's necessary when Your bot need send Message with **Inline Button** to Channel.
In Normally way, when bot send message to Channel , **Inline Button**s are **Not** shown on channel post!

Comment: What do you want to do? I don't understand

Comment: @MarcoBuster send Inline Message to Channel with bot , without any Human user!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send message to Bots itself. You can test it with the Bot ID. (api/bot<**botID**>)

[output screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3FT9.jpg)